# Where can I get a replacement for cracked window trim?

Tags: windows, trim, pvc

I cracked some window trim in my condo. Where can I get a replacement? It looks like PVC material but I'm not able to find anything at Home Depot. Is this because its commercial material or something?

[image]

---

OK I ended up just ripping it off.

Clips into the side of the window

[image]
[image]

[image: clips into the side of the window]

Comment: We try to stay away from doing shopping. You know what you need, shop til you drop.

Comment: Can you take the broken piece out and post a picture of shape?  Right now it just looks to be a flat piece that snaps into grooves, about the same as window blinds.  The colour should be the hardest to match if so.

Comment: The new picture looks like a custom moulding from the window maker.  The condo building department/maintenance should have information for the window maker or the trim maker in their records to get replacements.